# Linking a button to a row, and highlighting row when clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I've added a (Form Control) button to each row of data. The user then navigates to the relevant row and clicks the button to transfer that data in that row to another worksheet via a script that runs.  What I would like is that when the button is clicked, the selected row is 'greyed out'.  Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: greyed out and uneditable, or just greyed out?

Comment: `selection.entirerow.interior.color = rgb(200,200,200)` ... how bout this?

Comment: Hi Rosetta, no I just need it 'greyed out' (really just to show which rows have been selected).  Your suggestion has worked perfectly, thanks for your help!